# What is the equation for Garman-Klass volatility?

Tags: volatility

I want to calculate realized/historical volatility for the underlying products of various options using the Garman-Klass estimator, but I can't see to find an equation, although I know it involves OHLC data. In the comments there is a link to the equation, but I still am looking for a little explanation. Why does this work? What is the variable "F"?

Comment: Google is your best friend, http://www.todaysgroep.nl/media/236846/measuring_historic_volatility.pdf

Comment: I found this, but was hoping for a better explanation. For example, what is the variable "F"? Frequency? Is this suppose to be the sqrt(252) to annualize the volatility?

Comment: My Google-fu didn't turn up anything great so I will produce something below. Credits to @joshuaulrich for the TTR R-package I used as source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [R TTR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/TTR.pdf) the Garman-Klass volatility is given by

```
# Historical Open-High-Low-Close Volatility: Garman Klass
# https://web.archive.org/web/20100326172550/http://www.sitmo.com/eq/402
if( calc=="garman.klass" ) {
  s <- sqrt( N/n * runSum( .5 * log(OHLC[,2]/OHLC[,3])^2 -
             (2*log(2)-1) * log(OHLC[,4]/OHLC[,1])^2 , n ) )
}
```

which corresponds to*

$$
 \sigma = \sqrt{ \frac{Z}{n} \sum
  \left[ \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle
\left( \log \frac{H_i}{L_i} \right)^2  - (2\log 2-1)
\left( \log \frac{C_i}{O_i} \right)^2 \right] }.
$$

I think this code is fairly self-explanatory but what's what?

`Z =` Number of closing prices in a year, `n =` number of historical prices used for the volatility estimate.

* $\LaTeX$ taken from the vignette.

Comment: I like when my documentation helps non-users of my code. :)

Comment: It really is excellent, better than the papers Google gives. Thanks for that!