# What is the formula for Intraday and overnight volatility?

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility

I'm a noob trying to calculate IntraDay and Overnight Volatility.

For **Intraday volatility** we can get the annualization factor with the following:

Length (hours, Open to Close): 6.5

Time frames per day: 24 / 6.5 = 3.6923

Time frames per year: 252 * 3.6923 = 930.4596

Annualization factor: SQRT(930.4596) = **30.5034**

For **Overnight** volatility, the annualization factor is:

Length (hours, Close to Open): 17.5

Time frames per day: 24 / 17.5 = 1.3714

Time frames per year: 252 * 1.3714 = 345.5928

Annualization factor: SQRT(345.5928) = **18.5901**

With these parameters, I can calculate **intraday volatility** as the standard deviation of the 20 most recent **open-to-close** price changes, multiplied by the annualization factor, **30.5034**

And overnight volatility can be calculated by the standard deviation of the 20 most recent **close-to-open** price changes, multiplied by the annualization factor, **18.5901**

It seems like this should be pretty straightforward since I have all the inputs but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, especially in thinkorswim.

For example, I tried editing ThinkorSwim's default historical volatility study to the following (I only changed the the last two lines from the bottom):

```
#
# TD Ameritrade IP Company, Inc. (c) 2007-2017
#

declare lower;

input length = 20;
input basis = {default Annual, Monthly, Weekly, Daily};

def ap = getAggregationPeriod();

assert(ap >= AggregationPeriod.MIN, "Study can only be calculated for time-aggregated charts: " + ap);

def barsPerDay = (regularTradingEnd(getYyyyMmDd()) - regularTradingStart(getYyyyMmDd())) / ap;
def barsPerYear =
    if ap > AggregationPeriod.WEEK then 12
    else if ap == AggregationPeriod.WEEK then 52
    else if ap >= AggregationPeriod.DAY then 252 * AggregationPeriod.DAY / ap
    else 252 * barsPerDay;

def basisCoeff;
switch (basis) {
case Annual:
    basisCoeff = 1;
case Monthly:
    basisCoeff = 12;
case Weekly:
    basisCoeff = 52;
case Daily:
    basisCoeff = 252;
}

def clLog = log(open / close[1]);
plot HV = stdev(clLog, length) * 30.5;
HV.SetDefaultColor(GetColor(0));
```

Is this correct? Is there a simpler thinkscript/formula? Thanks very much. I appreciate it.

** Here's the graph its spitting out:
[image]

Comment: Looks Good. What's the issue here?

Comment: I'm honestly just not sure if the output is correct. Just want to verify. I just added an image of the intraday and overnight below implied/historical. For example, why is the line for overnight (0.89) lower than the line for intraday (0.40) and ImpVolatility (0.86)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks correct to me, the open of the last bar divided by the close of the previous bar.

```
def clLog = log(open / close[1]);
```

For intraday it would be...

```
def clLog = log(open / close);
```

Also, to answer your comment, when combining plots all lines are scaled to use the full vertical space of the graph (i.e. 0-100%) which is why a lower number value from one line may show above a higher value from another line.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a greast summary on volatility estimation [here](http://www.todaysgroep.nl/media/236846/measuring_historic_volatility.pdf).

I also suggest to get familiar with Garman-Klass volatility. Discussed [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/11306/what-is-the-equation-for-garman-klass-volatility) and in this [article](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/files/a_estimation_of_security_price.pdf).