# Estimating Intraday Volatility with OHLC Data

Tags: volatility, etf, intraday, ohlc

I'm trying to estimate intraday volatility for some ETFs, but don't have the intraday data to actually calculate it. I do, however, have historical daily OHLC data for the ETFs. I thought I saw somewhere that one could estimate/approximate intraday volatility with OHLC data, but I'm struggling to find it now. Does anybody know this estimation?

Comment: Have you tried searching? Google gives some relevant answers. Also [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/11306/what-is-the-equation-for-garman-klass-volatility).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the link.